# Product with multiple code in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have Two Tables

**Product** : id,name
**product_code** : id,product_id,code

I want following output in PHP Mysql

```
Mobile : 1258,5697,569845
Computer : 5789,1467,58946
```

where mobile and computer is product name and numbers are product code... (concatenation of product code)

Comment: How about you post a mysql statement which should be used to access the DB ? And the php-snipped which should generate the output ?

Comment: select p.*,pc.*,GROUP_CONCAT(product_code) from Product p,  pc where pc.product_id=p.id group by p.name;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.name, 
       c.code 
FROM   product AS p 
       INNER JOIN product_code AS c 
               ON p.id = c.product_id
```

Should do the trick, assuming its a one to one mapping

Comment: @SachinSanchaniya You should show that you've done at least some of the work yourself. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: @SachinSanchaniya  Well then you need to write proper questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask